# WooCommerce coupon hook argument NULL when using filter woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data

Tags: filters, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to write a plugin to allow using coupons that are stored on a separate system and can be accessed through a Web API. To that end, I want to use the filter `woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data`.

The source code is

```
$coupon = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data', false, $this->code )
```

My code in the plugin constructor:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data', array($this, 'filter_woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data'));
```

And the function:

```
public function filter_woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data($arg1, $arg2) {
    var_dump($arg1);
    var_dump($arg2);
    return null;
}
```

And what I'm getting is `bool(false) NULL`, i.e. the second arg which is supposed to be the coupon code is null. I have no idea what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell add_filter how many arguments it accepts (2) example:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data', array( $this, 'filter_woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data' ), 10, 2 );
```

Be sure to enable WP_Debug - http://wpexplorer-themes.com/total/docs/enabling-wp-debug/ - on your server, because you should have gotten an error when trying to do this without the added argument.

Also I highly recommend using static classes when dealing with filters for easiser modification by developers using child themes or extra plugins. Example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data', array( 'YOUR_CLASS_NAME', 'filter_woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data' ), 10, 2 );

public static function filter_woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data( $arg1, $arg2 ) {
    var_dump($arg1);
    var_dump($arg2);
    return null;
}
```

This way a developer can always use this if needed:

```
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data', array( 'YOUR_CLASS_NAME', 'filter_woocommerce_get_shop_coupon_data' ), 10, 2 );
```

When using $this WordPress assigns a dynamic name and it's harder to modify things if needed. Just a tip. Maybe not for this plugin bug for others ;)

Comment: I highly recommend using static functions though for your class - this way it's easier for a developer to remove your code. See my edited response ;)

Comment: Thank you!!! And the 10 is its priority, am I right?

Comment: Yes 10 is the priority ;) But you can use anything - if 10 isn't working use 20 maybe. If this is intended to override ANYTHING you can also use PHP_INT_MAX